# Neural translation model - alignment as a latent variable or as a trainable part of the model

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, recurrent-neural-networks

I consider the neural machine translation method in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.0473.pdf.

I understand that the intuition here, as the title says, is to jointly train alignment and translation. Alignment is part of the model, the alignment model is

$ e_{ij} = a(s_{i-1}, h_{j}) $

where function $a$ scores the match between information around time j represented by an annotation $h_{j}$ and the translation model output at time $i-1$ represented by the RNN's hidden state $s_{i-1}$.

I kind of understand we obtain a big model intricating the alignment part embedded by the annotations and the translation part, in particular with annotations depending on the hidden states of the translation model.

It says,

```
Note that unlike in traditional machine translation, 
the alignment is not considered to be a latent variable.
```

*Here my question, how is a model like, which considers alignment as a latent variable?*

It might be similar to the approach described in this article, with the "alignment model" made "not trainable". In this case, how is alignment computed? How would one formalize this translation model where alignment is a latent variable?